# Валидация госномера

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Нужно что бы первые 2 символа были буквы, 3-5 были цифры

```
$(document).on('input', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
  if($(this).val().length <= 2){
    this.value = this.value.replace (/[^а-я ]/g, '');
  }
  if($(this).val().length >= 3 && $(this).val().length < 5){
    this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9+]/, '');
  }
});
```

Пробовал так, почему то после ввода букв цифры удаляют буквы и ввод происходит сначала

```js
другой способ
$(document).on('input', 'input[name="start"]', function (){
    this.value = this.value.replace (/[^А-Яа-я ]/g, '');
    if($(this).val().length == 1){
        $('input[name="center"]').focus();
    }
    });
    $(document).on('input', 'input[name="center"]', function (){
        this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9+]/, '');
        if($(this).val().length == 3){
            $('input[name="end"]').focus();
        }
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('input[name="start"]').focus();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('input', 'input[name="end"]', function (){
        this.value = this.value.replace (/[^А-Яа-я ]/g, '');
        if($(this).val().length == 2){
            $('input[name="reg"]').focus();
        }
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('input[name="center"]').focus();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('input', 'input[name="reg"]', function (){
        this.value = this.value.replace (/[^0-9+]/, '');
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('input[name="end"]').focus();
        }
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(){
        $(this).css( "color", "black" ); 
      });
```

Сами input:

```html
<div class="gos-inp">
    <input type="text" name="start" class="gos-inp_start" maxlength="1" placeholder="А">
    <input type="text" name="center" class="gos-inp_center" maxlength="3" placeholder="001">
    <input type="text" name="end" class="gos-inp_end" maxlength="2" placeholder="АА">
    <input type="text" name="reg" class="gos-inp_reg" maxlength="2" placeholder="27">
    <img src="gos.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Прочитайте про `replace`, прежде чем использовать его в данной задаче. научитесь читать мануалы.

Comment: Что я не так сделал конкретно в данном примере?

Comment: replace не подходит для вашей задачи, используйте match

Comment: Вам ведь надо проверить соответствие ввода? Или вы хотите недопустить неправильный ввод вообще?

Comment: Я сделал немного по другому, сделал не один input а 4, не знаю на сколько данное решение верное, работает, но проблемы с переходом на предыдущий инпут в случае удаления символа, но думаю это решаемо, код приложил в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ГОСТом для использования на знаках разрешены 12 букв кириллицы, имеющие графические аналоги в латинском алфавите — А, В, Е, К, М, Н, О, Р, С, Т, У и Х.
> [(источник)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Строим вот такую регулярку - **`^(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){1}[0-9]{3}(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){2}$`**, где

```
^ - начало строки
(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){1} - набор букв по ГОСТу в гос.номере (только одна буква)
[0-9]{3} - группа из трёх чисел (000-999)
(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){2} - группа из двух букв по ГОСТу
$ - конец строки

ещё добавим флаги:
g - глобальный поиск
i - регистронезависимый шаблон
```

Результат:

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){ // вешаем обработчик на инпут
  let val = $(this).val(); // получаем значение в переменную
  if(val.length === 6) { // нам нужно, чтобы значение было шесть символов в длину
    if(val.match(/^(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){1}[0-9]{3}(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){2}$/gi)) { // запускаем проверку по нашей регулярке
      $(this).css('color', 'green'); // красим текст инпута в зелёный, если это гос. номер по ГОСТу
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', 'darkred'); // красим текст в красный, если нет
    }
  } else $(this).css('color', 'inherit'); // если длина значение не шесть символов, то возращаем дефолтный цвет
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="А000АА" maxlength="6" size="6">
<select>
  <option>Тут выбор региона</option>
</select>
```

---

P.s. Я не стал бы колхозить это несколькими инпутами, а выбор региона перенёс бы на список (`<select>`).

Comment: ай молодец, приплёл ГОСТ

Comment: не знаю, какую там задачу автор решает,  но номера мотоциклов, автобусов, прицепов, спецтранспорта имеют несколько иной формат чем `x000xx`

Comment: второй паттерн повотрять не надо кстати, можно сослаться на него через `(?1)` т.е. что-то вроде `^([авекмнорстух])\d{3}((?1){2})\d{2,3}rus$`

Comment: это кстати говоря можно указать в `<input pattern="..."/>`

Comment: Клиент сторону, легко подменить, советую, делать такое на стороне сервера тоже.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но мне нужно что бы пользователь не смог бы вводить допустим там где цифры вводить буквы... Поэтому другого варианта кроме как колхозить 3 импутами я не вижу, к сожалению

Comment: @teran, js не поддерживает `(?1)`

Comment: `(а|в|е|к|м|н|о|р|с|т|у|х){1}` - жесть.

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно. но на бэкенде все равно проверять, так что пригодится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, первая моя, самостоятельная, регулярка, не ругайтесь :D